# Magento 1.9 css and js not load with https

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2

when I enable free SSL in cloud-flare, my magento website stops loading properly. Basically CSS and JS doesn't load but without HTTPS the website works fine, but with HTTPS website does not load CSS and JS. I tried with below code in index.php, but didn't work.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && (443 == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])) $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Please help!!

Comment: i tried with if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
but didn't work!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under System>Config>Web>General>Secure

You need to set the Use Secure URLs in Frontend and Use Secure URLs in Admin to yes.